# Upgrading to Spring Security 4 breaks login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to upgrade to Spring 4.0.1 from Spring 3.2.8 / Spring Security 3.2.4. After logging in, it redirects me back to the login page with no errors in the log file.

Here is my Spring Security 3 config:

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Spring Security 4 config:

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class= "org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Login form:

```
    <form class="form-signin" action='<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />' method="POST">
        <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h3>

        <input type="text" class="input-block-level loginTextInput" placeholder="Username" name="j_username" id="j_username" autofocus="autofocus" >
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level loginTextInput" placeholder="Password" name="j_password" id="j_password">
        <button class="onWhite" type="submit">Sign in</button>

        <div>&nbsp;</div>

        <c:if test="${param.login_error == '1'}">
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <strong>Error:</strong> Invalid username/password combination.          
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout == '2'}">
            <div class="alert">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
        </c:if>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security - Authentication not working even the credentials are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970359/spring-security-authentication-not-working-even-the-credentials-are-correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default form attribute names changed from v3 to v4. Should now simply be `password` and `username` but can obviously be configured if something else required.

So simply changing the name attributes as below should fix the issue:

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level loginTextInput" 
    placeholder="Username" name="username" id="j_username" autofocus="autofocus" >
<input type="password" class="input-block-level loginTextInput" 
     placeholder="Password" name="password" id="j_password">
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login

> The form-login@username-parameter attribute default value changed from
>   j_username to username. If an application explicitly provides the
>   attribute, no action is required for the migration.
>
> The form-login@password-parameter attribute default value changed from
>   j_password to password. If an application explicitly provides the
>   attribute, no action is required for the migration.